# htaccess .php extension removal: Getting internal error while accessing url with trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to remove .php extensions from my urls making it user friendly.

I am trying to rewrite this url: example.com/about.php
as both example.com/about & example/about/

So, here i am trying to get the url with & without trailing slash.

Also, i am trying to return a 404 error while accessing with .php

All things are going smoothly. But, getting an error while accessing the url with trailing slash. like this one: example/about/

Please help me to fix the issue.

Thank You in advance.

I tried other codes, modifying "/?$" but not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    Options +MultiViews

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```